# Как отрендерить select при ajax-запросе?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Суть такая: я выбираю первый `select` и в зависимости от значениея `value` (из первого селекта), у меня строится второй `select`. т.е. я отправляю **get**-запрос с параметром `code` в контроллер и хочу получить в ответ нужный мне массив. 
Мне нужно получить данные с контроллера.

Данные в контроллер отправляются. Там на основе этих данных у меня появляется массив `@point`

Вопрос в том: Как отрендерить теперь это во вьюхе. В *partial* переменная `@point` есть с нужными значениями(когда выбрал город). Скорее как с помощью *js* ее отрендерить.

**index.html.erb**:

```
    <form action="/baskets" data-remote="true">
    <p>Город</p>
    <select name="country_id" id="country_id">
        <option value="0">- выберите город -</option>
        <% @city.sort.each do |city| %>
          <option value="<%=city[1]%>"><%= city[0] %> </option>
        <% end %>
    </select>

    <br><br>
    <p>Пункт выдачи:</p>
    <%= render :partial => 'points', :locals => {:point => @point} %>

    <br><br>
    <p>Стоимость доставки:</p>

</form>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#country_id').change(function () {
          var country_id = $(this).val();
          $('#region_id').html('<option>загрузка...</option>');

          $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: '/baskets',
              data: { code: country_id },
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(){
                $('#region_id').html('<%= j(render :partial => "points", :locals => {:point => @point}) -%>');
                $('#region_id').attr('disabled', false);
              }
          });
      });
  });
</script>
```

**_points.html.erb**

```
<select name="region_id" id="region_id" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="0">- выберите пункт -</option>
  <% @point.sort.each do |point| %>
    <option value="<%=point[1]%>"><%= point[0] %> </option>
  <% end %>
</select>
```

**UPD**:

Когда смотрю в инспекторе браузера мой запрос, вкладку Preview, то там весь мой JS код, где в Ajax success весь мой нужный `select`,  я так предполагал, что там должен быть просто мой select, без JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#country_id').change(function () {
      var country_id = $(this).val();
      $('#region_id').html('<option>загрузка...</option>');

      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: '/baskets',
          data: { code: country_id },
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(){
            // срендерил
            $('#poop').html('<select name=\"region_id\" id=\"region_id\" disabled=\"disabled\" data-remote=\"true\">\n    <option value=\"0\">- выберите пункт -<\/option>\n      <option value=\"29101\">163000, Архангельск г, Воскресенская ул, д.105 <\/option>\n      <option value=\"204\">163000, Архангельск г, Воскресенская ул, д.12 <\/opвведите сюда кодtion>\n      <option value=\"29041\">163000, Архангельск г, Троицкий пр-кт, д.158 <\/option>\n      <option value=\"29071\">163002, Архангельск г, Ломоносова пр-кт, д.16, корпус 1 <\/option>\n      <option value=\"29081\">163009, Архангельск г, Ленинградский пр-кт, д.40, строение 3 <\/option>\n      <option value=\"29141\">163020, Архангельск г, Советская ул, д.32 <\/option>\n      <option value=\"29111\">163053, Архангельск г, Аэропорт Архангельск тер, д.8 <\/option>\n      <option value=\"29131\">163065, Архангельск г, Московский пр-кт, д.49, оф. 2-09 <\/option>\n<\/select>');
            $('#region_id').attr('disabled', false);
          }
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: `render :partial => "points"` -- в множественном числе?..

Comment: да, и в js скрипте и в форме в html

Comment: Приведённый в вопросе паршл в единственном числе. Хотя судя по коду, рендерит он множество точек.

Comment: @D-side мой паршл тоже во множественном. Вообще я немного поправил код, еще js код находится в `index.html.erb`

Comment: Ещё странно, что вы указали при рендере локальную переменную `point`, а обходите значение инстансного `@point`, и в блоке затеняете (shadow) наружный `point` блочным. И раз это набор точек, почему бы не назвать его сразу `points`?

Comment: @D-side т.е. в паршле я итерирую `point`, а не `@point`? а про блок не понял

Comment: Да ну? А что такое `@point.sort.each do |point|`? :) Вы определяете таким образом новую локальную переменную `point`, которая перекрывает локальную переменную с таким же именем снаружи (вы ею не пользуетесь, но она есть).

Comment: @D-side Прошу прощения, там вопрос был) я исправил. и комментарий и код, так как вы сказали.

Comment: @D-side Но с рендером так и не разобрался, он все равно не выводит список. По идее он просто не обновляет этот пустой select (хотя переменная там есть, все вроде более или менее правильно)

Comment: Возьмите отладчик, посмотрите везде ли те данные, которые вы ожидаете.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62924/discussion-between-dmitriy-and-d-side).